# scikit-learn multiprocessing from Celery worker

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, celery

I want to run some `scikit-learn` things as a job using `celery`. The problem is `scikit-learn` refuses to/can't use multiprocessing from a celery worker process. Typically it will give a warning like:

> [2018-10-23 09:24:45,858: WARNING/PoolWorker-1]
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py:739:
>   UserWarning: Loky-backed parallel loops cannot be called in a
>   multiprocessing, setting n_jobs=1

And it will continue to process in series.

I'm not so familiar with Python's multiprocessing options so I'm getting lost in a jungle of libraries called `multiprocessing`, `joblib`, `billiard`, `loky`. Apparently `celery` uses `billiard` internally. `scikit-learn=0.20.0` uses a built-in version of `loky`.

Some relevant GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4551#issuecomment-370386892
- https://github.com/celery/billiard/issues/168

Comment: Is scitkit-learn the right library then? What are you trying to do? You might be better off using sparkml or h2o or something built to handle multiprocessing

Comment: I'm building a (web-based) tool to do classification on texts (with some natural language processing tools & `scikit-learn`'s classifiers). I'm already quite invested in `scikit-learn`, so switching to a different tool would be quite cumbersome. I'm using `scikit-learn` pipelines a lot, of which many steps are in principle parallelized, but they just refuse to run so when it's running from a celery worker. I would even prefer replacing celery to replacing `scikit-learn` actually.

Comment: I thought sklearn had decided that running over a cluster was beyond the scope of the project and that they weren't going to support it. I think I read that as part of their justification for not having deep learning algorithms. You might have to write your own wrapper for Celery like these guys did for Spark: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/08/auto-scaling-scikit-learn-with-apache-spark.html

Comment: Clusters are beyond my current scope also. I just want to be able to utilize the cores on a single machine right now. I will check later if some sort of celery wrapper will work for that then!

Comment: @Dan, thanks, it has become clear to me that to do proper parallellization I should step away from my current approach and use something like `Spark` or `Dask`. I'm myself not so familiar with distributed computing so I'll try to get some help from colleagues that are :).